# How to change Keras/tensorflow version in Google colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm using keras/tensorflow on google colaboratory and I need to go back to previous versions of them.

The problem is when I run `!pip install q keras==1.2.2` , the kernel shows keras 1.2.2 installed but when I check it using `keras.__version_` it shows 2.1.6 . And same case is with tensorflow.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 16):

I had this issue yesterday. I was rather surprised that installing packages did not have an effect.
But I realised then that I needed to restart the kernel. In Colab this is called `Restart runtime`. After restart the new version should be available for you.

*Here you find the restart:*

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your command `!pip install q keras==1.2.2` for Keras is okay, just you need to restart runtime as other answers mentioned.
but for tensorflow you should use `%tensorflow_version 1.x`.
as they said [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb#scrollTo=8UvRkm1JGUrk):

> Avoid Using pip install with GPUs and TPUs We recommend against using
>   pip install to specify a particular TensorFlow version for both GPU
>   and TPU backends. Colab builds TensorFlow from source to ensure
>   compatibility with our fleet of accelerators. Versions of TensorFlow
>   fetched from PyPI by pip may suffer from performance problems or may
>   not work at all.

and as it says, when I tried to downgrade my TensorFlow to 1.5 with pip, it does not recognize GPU and just trained my model with cpu.

Comment: Google Colab removed support for TensorFlow 1 in their latest release of 2022/8/11.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest colab, when you upgrade or downgrade a module, in the output cell you will automatically see the statement:

"WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime:
  [scipy]
You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.

" asking you to restart the runtime along with a button for it.